# shadow map for second life not working correctly

Tags: uv, shadows

so I have a object in blender and im trying to create a shadow map for it

[image]

for some reason the shadowmap is all wrong and when uploading the image to the game it is ruined

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Sam

Comment: It would help if you explained why you think the shadow map is wrong, and give us a screenshot so we have some more objective information. The more precise you are, the bigger the chance you get a helpful answer.

Comment: If you look at the uv texture map you can see that there is way to much black in the but in the render its not there, here is a picture of it in second life https://gyazo.com/a8411c3b8affe9844fcea7016f423349

Comment: It looks like you're using the shadow map as a diffuse texture. That won't work, I guess, because a shadow map contains info about the shadow, and not the diffuse reflection.